# Unknown symbol about divisibility in paper re FLT

Tags: number-theory, notation

What does $\bigslopedwedge$ symbol mean? I saw it in Nigel Boston's paper about FLT. It is an upside down V (a wedge) but not symmetric. The right leg is vertical and the left is not. First arg is a single number and the second is the product of 2 numbers. It clearly does NOT mean "does not divide". Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is $v_p(n)= \max \left \{k \in \mathbb{N}: p^k|n \right \}$ for prime $p$

Comment: @M10687 $v$ doesn't look like an upside down V.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I read that as just "looks like a v." Disregard.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/869.pdf)? Which page?

Comment: @user236182, Lemma 1.4 has a "does not divide" but the OP does not accept that meaning. Need a page number

Comment: @user236182, Lemma 1.5 has a mistyped "does not divide," maybe that is it. page ix Another one on page xi. On page ix you can see variation in where the vertical and diagonal lines meet.

Comment: correspond to \nmid displayed as $\nmid$

Comment: It just seems odd that in a paper with "does not divide" right there the writer/editor could make such a mistake which is why I assumed they did not intend "does not divide". Having gotten hung up there I was frustrated and did not go further. It seems I may have given up too soon. Based on the answer below. Still it seems curious, no?

Answer (score 2):

From this page, it is clear that the symbol for "does not divide" was composed from two symbols with some overlap, and the overlap varies. I count six "does not divide" signs on this page. In two of them, the lines meet near midpoints, as we want. For two, they meet at about the 3/4 points. For two, including the first in Lemma 1.5 and the third one on the page, the lines meet at endpoints, as described in the question.

[image]